# Is there a way to seperate with a <br> each time the order property finds a change?

Tags: rally

I'm working on a defect list custom app that uses a queryConfig to populate results of a defect. I'm currently sorting the results using the `order` property.

My question is: is it possible to somehow detect when the criteria of the `order` sort changes and to make a break?

For example- let's say the list that is populating is a list of food sorted by categorization. In our order property we will sort these DESC. It may look like this:

`Apples
Bananas
Strawberries
Carrots
Lettuce`

Now within the food categorization, there is a Fruits category and a Vegetables category. The question again, can I somehow know when the Vegetables sort is happening and then perform a 
 to make the results look grouped?

Using the example from above, we would want to achieve:

`Apples
Bananas
Strawberries`

`Carrots
Lettuce`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting via the `Order` parameter is done server-side, so I don't think there's a way to identify changes in groupings client-side without inspecting the data.

Since you're using AppSDK 1.x, this may be a situation where using an Array of queryConfig's could be useful to attain groupings of results that match your desired groupings. Then you could do something similar to the following:

```
 var queryConfig = [];
 queryConfig[0] = {
  type : 'HierarchicalRequirement', 
  key : 'fruit_stories',
  query: '(c_FoodCategory = "Fruits")', 
  fetch: 'Name,FormattedID,Description,c_FoodCategory'
 };
 queryConfig[1] = {
  type : 'HierarchicalRequirement',
  key : 'veggie_stories',
  query: '(c_FoodCategory = "Vegetables")', 
  fetch: 'Name,FormattedID,Description,c_FoodCategory'
 };

  var rallyDataSource;
  rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
                           '__PROJECT_OID__',
                           '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
                           '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__'); 
  rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, processResults);
}

var processResults = function(results) {
    var fruit_stories = results['fruit_stories'];
    var veggie_stories = results['veggie_stories'];
    var aDiv = document.getElementById("aDiv");

    // Output fruit stories
    for (var i=0; i<fruit_stories.length; i++) {
       story = fruit_stories[i];
       storyInfo += story.Name + 
                   ', ' + story.FormattedID + 
                   ', ' + story.c_FoodCategory + '<br>';
     }
     aDiv.innerHTML = '<strong>Name, State, Food Category</strong><br/>';
     aDiv.innerHTML += storyInfo;

     // Add break
     aDiv.innerHTML += "<br/>

    // Output veggie stories
    for (var i=0; i<veggie_stories.length; i++) {
       story = veggie_stories[i];
       storyInfo += story.Name + 
                   ', ' + story.FormattedID + 
                   ', ' + story.c_FoodCategory + '<br>';
     }
     aDiv.innerHTML = '<strong>Name, State, Food Category</strong><br/>';
     aDiv.innerHTML += storyInfo;

     // Add break
     aDiv.innerHTML += "<br/>               
};
```

You may wish to consider using `rally.sdk.ui.Table` for displaying your output results - it provides a much cleaner visual display of columnar information.

Also, if you're interested in considering AppSDK 2.0, its [Grid component](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.grid.Grid) contains a configuration attribute for automated grouping. See this example:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/groupable-grid